# How can I fix "Can't install" issue in Google Play for Google Pixel phones?

Tags: android, google-play, google-pixel

My app was published to Google Play in 2019 and it is now version 2.2.17. Everything was fine until the latest version 2 weeks ago. I got a number of feedbacks from the users saying they cannot install the app from Google Play.

When they attempt to install it, they get the message as can be seen in the following screenshot.

I notice that ALL OF THE USERS having this issue are using Google Pixel phones. Some of them did mention that they upgraded the OS to Android 12.

I advised them to clear Google Play's cache and data, and re-login their Google account, as well as some troubleshootings that can be found on Google. However, it seems to not work for some of them.


I would like to ask if there is any other solution to fix this.

Also, is there any chance that the APK, the compiling process, or deployment process went wrong? I am not sure for this case because it seems all non-Google Pixel phones can still install the app normally.

Thank you


[image]

Comment: debug your app on [Android 12 emulator](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/get#on_emulator) and share the log

Comment: have you got any solution to it? If yes, please share, it will be very helpful for me